# evil-winrm error connecting

Tags: ldap

I can't connect using `evil-winrm` directly. But when I use `exegol` it works

command used:
 `evil-winrm -i ip -u 'user' -p 'password'`

error using `evil-winrm`:
`Error: An error of type OpenSSL::Digest::DigestError happened, message is Digest initialization failed: initialization error`

Already tried changed the next config files but didn't work:

file: `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

```
...
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
...
```

Also tried the following:

1.- get certificate: `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect ip | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ldapserver.pem`

2.- update config ldap `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`

```
...
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ldapserver.pem
...
```

3.- connect using `ldapsearch` command: `ldapsearch -H ldaps://ip -x -D "CN=user,DC=dc,DC=tld" -w "pass" -b "DC=dc,DC=tld"`

Comment: What OS, version, etc.?

Comment: evil-winrm v3.5
Ubuntu 22.10